# mlock a program from a wrapper

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

Just a quick question (I hope). How would you allocate an address space via mlock and then launch an application within that space?

For instance I have a binary that launches from a wrapper program that configures the environment. I only have access to the wrapper code and would like to have the binary launch in a certain address space. Is it possible to do this from the wrapper?

Thanks!

Comment: What part of the application are you expecting to launch within that address space? (And, out of curiosity: why?)

Comment: I am trying to launch the binary.... Its not "part of" an application it is the application... Think of it as the wrapper launches a program that is an I/O driver. It reads info from a specific address and the writes it out to the network. You don't care how it does it but you would like to restrict it to memory to prevent it from being page swapped. So my question was just how would you lock it memory...

Comment: More specifically: what do you expect the application to use this specific address space for? The application's primary executable image? Data? Shared libraries? Dynamic allocations?

Comment: I would say all of the above... Again the overall goal is to prevent it from being swapped. If there are better ways of preventing this I am all hears. Just I need to keep the way it launches the same. (Wrapper -> Binary)

Answer (score 5):

If you have the sources for the program, add a command-line option so that the program calls [`mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlockall.2.html) at some point. That locks it in memory.

If you want to control the address spaces the kernel loads the program into, you need to delve into kernel internals. Most likely, there is no reason to do so; only people with really funky hardware would.

If you don't have the sources, or don't want to recompile the program, then you can create a dynamic library that executes the command, and inject it into the process via `LD_PRELOAD`.

Save the following as `lockall.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void wrerr(const char *p)
{
    if (p) {
        const char *q = p + strlen(p);
        ssize_t     n;

        while (p < q) {
            n = write(STDERR_FILENO, p, (size_t)(q - p));
            if (n > 0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != -1 || errno != EINTR)
                return;
        }
    }
}

static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void init(void)
{
    int saved_errno = errno;

    if (mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE) == -1) {
        const char *errmsg = strerror(errno);
        wrerr("Cannot lock all memory: ");
        wrerr(errmsg);
        wrerr(".\n");
        exit(127);
    } else
        wrerr("All memory locked.\n");

    errno = saved_errno;
}
```

Compile it to a dynamic library `liblockall.so` using

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -fPIC -shared lockall.c -Wl,-soname,liblockall.so -o liblockall.so
```

Install the library somewhere typical, for example

```
sudo install -o 0 -g 0 -m 0664 liblockall.so /usr/lib/
```

so you can run any binary, and lock it into memory, using

```
LD_PRELOAD=liblockall.so binary arguments..
```

If you install the library somewhere else (not listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`), you'll need to specify path to the library, like

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/liblockall.so binary arguments..
```

Typically, you'll see the message `Cannot lock all memory: Cannot allocate memory.` printed by the interposed library, when running commands as a normal user. (The superuser, or root, typically has no such limit.) This is because for obvious reasons, most Linux distributions limit the amount of memory an unprivileged user can lock into memory; this is the `RLIMIT_MEMLOCK` [resource limit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html). Run `ulimit -l` to see the per-process resource limits currently set (for the current user, obviously).

I suggest you set a suitable limit of how much memory the process can run, running e.g. [`ulimit -l 16384`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-ulimit) bash-built-in before executing the (to set the limit to 16384*1024 bytes, or 16 MiB), if running as superuser (root). If the process leaks memory, instead of crashing your machine (because it locked all available memory), the process will die (from `SIGSEGV`) if it exceeds the limit. That is, you'd start your process using

```
ulimit -l 16384
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/liblockall.so binary arguments..
```

if using Bash or dash shell.

If running as a dedicated user, most distributions use the `pam_limits.so` PAM module to set the resource limits "automatically". The limits are listed either in the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, or in a file in the `/etc/security/limits.d/` subdirectory, using [this format](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.conf.5.html); the `memlock` item specifies the amount of memory each process can lock, in units of 1024 bytes. So, if your service runs as user `mydev`, and you wish to allow the user to lock up to 16 megabytes = 16384*1024 bytes per process, then add line `mydev - memlock 16384` into `/etc/security/limits.conf` or `/etc/security/limits.d/mydev.conf`, whichever your Linux distribution prefers/suggests.

Prior to PAM, [shadow-utils](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.5.html) were used to control the resource limits. The memlock resource limit is specified in units of 1024 bytes; a limit of 16 megabytes would be set using `M16384`. So, if using shadow-utils instead of PAM, adding line `mydev M16384` (followed by whatever the other limits you wish to specify) to `/etc/limits` should do the trick.